# Importing foreign language character csv into xampp mysql

Tags: mysql, excel, xampp

Importing the data below from CSV into xampp mysql results in **????** and for some reason the "**ελ**" Greek characters cannot be inserted at all.

> ಭಾರತ 한국 ଭାରତ ভাৰত ভারত বাংলা қаз срб бг бел சிங்கப்பூர் мкд ею 中国 中國
>   భారత్ ලංකා ભારત भारतम् भारत भारोत укр 香港 台湾 台灣 мон ‏الجزائر‎ ‏عمان‎
>   ‏ایران‎ ‏امارات‎ ‏پاکستان‎ ‏الاردن‎ ‏بارت‎ ‏بھارت‎ ‏المغرب‎ ‏السعودية‎
>   ‏ڀارت‎ ‏سودان‎ ‏عراق‎ ‏مليسيا‎ 澳門 გე ไทย ‏سورية‎ рф ‏تونس‎ ελ ഭാരതം
>   ਭਾਰਤ ‏مصر‎ ‏قطر‎ இலங்கை இந்தியா հայ 新加坡 ‏فلسطين‎

I have tried `utf8_general_ci` and `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

I can't specify a character set other than `utf8/utf16` and a bunch of other ISO and other character set when I import the CSV.

Comment: Please do only post English here; if you need to add content in foreign languages, provide a translation that is marked as such.

Comment: @AndreasWolf it is in English related to the need for a foreign language import

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following

1. Please change your table and column collation as
   `utf8_general_ci`.Set your column type as `TEXT`.

   If you are using phpmyadmin, you can easily do it as given below.

[image]

2. After that,click the table, and then click the Import tab at the top
   of the page.Select your csv file(csv file data should match table
   columns) and click go.Ignore any errors.

[image]

3. Check to see the data is stored correctly

[image]